# Error installing unf_ext (0.0.9) with native extensions in Gemfile

Tags: c++, ruby, rubygems, g++

I am encountering an issue while running `bundle install` for a Ruby project with the following Gemfile:

```rb
ruby '2.3.1'

source 'http://www.rubygems.org'

gem 'aws-flow', '~> 2.4.0'
gem 'aws-sdk-core', '~> 3.65', '>= 3.65.1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.1'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.10.10'
gem 'activerecord', '~> 5.2', '>= 5.2.3'
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3', '= 1.3.9'
gem 'rubyzip', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.3'
gem 'mechanize', '~> 2.7', '>= 2.7.5'
gem 'slack-notifier', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.1'
gem 'minitest', '~> 5.8.4'
gem 'connection_pool', '~> 2.2.5'
gem 'httparty', '~> 0.19.1'
gem 'webrick', '~> 1.7.0'
gem 'net-http-persistent', '= 4.0.1'
```

The error occurs during the installation of the `unf_ext` gem with the following message:

```
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Fetching gem metadata from http://www.rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from http://www.rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from http://www.rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Using concurrent-ruby 1.2.2
Using minitest 5.8.5
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using arel 9.0.0
Using aws-eventstream 1.2.0
Using json 1.8.6
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Using lru_redux 0.8.4
Using aws-partitions 1.848.0
Using jmespath 1.6.2
Using aws-sigv2 1.1.0
Using connection_pool 2.2.5
Installing unf_ext 0.0.9 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.9/ext/unf_ext
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20231113-2866-7e5i1z.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lstdc++... yes
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/unf_ext-0.0.9/mkmf.log

current directory: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.9/ext/unf_ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.9/ext/unf_ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling unf.cc
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wdeclaration-after-statement’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit-function-declaration’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
unf.cc:39:3: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
   };
   ^
unf.cc:39:3: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
make: *** [unf.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0-static/unf_ext-0.0.9/gem_make.out
Using mime-types-data 3.2023.1003
Using multi_xml 0.6.0
Using net-http-digest_auth 1.4.1
Using ntlm-http 0.1.1
Using webrick 1.7.0
Using webrobots 0.1.2
Using rubyzip 1.3.0
Using slack-notifier 1.5.1
Using sqlite3 1.3.9
Using bundler 1.12.1
Using i18n 1.14.1
Using tzinfo 1.2.11
Using aws-sigv4 1.6.1
Using nokogiri 1.10.10
Using net-http-persistent 4.0.1
An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've checked the mkmf.log file as suggested, but I'm having trouble identifying why the `unf_ext` gem is being installed and what might be causing this compilation error. I did not explicitly include `unf_ext` in my Gemfile, and it seems to be a dependency of another gem.

Any guidance on how to resolve this issue or insights into why `unf_ext` is being installed would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, if there are specific versions of gems that need adjustmen?

Comment: Please do not cross-post. [The issue you have created on Github](https://github.com/knu/ruby-unf_ext/issues/74) is the  right place and the developers may be able to come up with a workaround there. In any case, the issue may have been introduced with [pull request 72](https://github.com/knu/ruby-unf_ext/pull/72) in unf-ext 0.0.9. If you use an older version of the gem, things may work for you again (given your very old general environment).

Comment: @HolgerJust, I can install version `unf-ext 0.0.8` no issue. I tried to install it manually it was successful. so I added this into the Gemfile `gem 'unf_ext', '~> 0.0.8'`. But I was getting the same error.

Comment: @AbhijithEa With `~> 0.0.8`, you are specifying `>= 0.0.8, < 0.1`. Instead, what you likely want to use is `= 0.0.8`.

Comment: @HolgerJust Thanks for your guidance. I resolved the issue by using an older version (gem 'unf_ext', '= 0.0.8' in Gemfile). While I understand this question may be better suited for the unf_ext GitHub repo, I'll leave it here for now until the 0.0.9 issue is fixed, this might help others.

Comment: @HolgerJust this is _the_ place to post problems like this

Answer (score 0):

The fix for now is to just add this to your Gemfile pinning the old version for now until a fix is available for this ticket. https://github.com/knu/ruby-unf_ext/issues/74

```
gem 'unf_ext', '= 0.0.8'
```